# How to insert the Datepicker into dynamically appended rows

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I need to insert Jquery's Datepicker into the table row(into td) which appended dynamically. Everething is ok besides Datepicker as it doesn't appear. 
What's wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#add").click(function(){

        var tableRow = "<tr><td></td><td id="datepicker"></td></tr>";

        $("table").append(tableRow); 
        $("#datepicker").datepicker();    
    });
});
```

Could you help me to fix it?

Comment: You want to add a class instead of duplicating element id's.

Comment: of course class for duplicating. thank you for the comment!

Answer (score 1):

Be careful about the kind of quotation marks.

Replace this:

```
var tableRow = "<tr><td></td><td id="datepicker"></td></tr>";
```

With this:

```
var tableRow = '<tr><td></td><td id="datepicker"></td></tr>';
```

I think, that "datepicker" is not a variable, but it's a **id**.

Comment: already solved. just forgot insert INPUT into TD: "<td><input id='datepicker' type='text'></td>";

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck in programing Datepicker :-)